# C++ Iterators return type

Tags: c++, iterator, googletest

I've never worked with iterators before, and I'm having trouble designing a custom iterator for a custom container class that I wrote.

Background: Using Google Tests API, these are the two test cases that I have:

```
TEST(RandomArray, End) {
    RandomArray r(17);
    int *b = r.begin();
    int *e = r.end();
    EXPECT_EQ(b + 17, e);
}

TEST(RandomArray, IteratorTypedef) {
    RandomArray r(7);
    for (RandomArray::iterator it = r.begin(); it != r.end(); ++it) {
        *it = 89;
        EXPECT_EQ(89, *it);
    }
}
```

Here's my header file and the code for the iterators:

```
class RandomArray
{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const RandomArray&);

public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        typedef iterator self_type;
        typedef int* pointer;
        typedef int& reference;
        self_type operator++() { self_type i = *this; ptr++; return i;}
        reference operator*() {return *ptr;}
        bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) {return ptr != rhs.ptr;}
    private:
        pointer ptr;
    };

    class const_iterator
    {
    public:
        typedef const_iterator self_type;
        typedef int* pointer;
        typedef int& reference;
        self_type operator++() { self_type i = *this; ptr++; return i;}
        const reference operator*() { return *ptr; }
        bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) {return ptr != rhs.ptr;}
    private:
        pointer ptr;
    };

    RandomArray();

    RandomArray(size_t);

    size_t size() const;

    int* begin();
    iterator begin();

    const int* begin() const;
    const iterator begin() const;

    int* end();
    iterator end();

    const int* end() const;
    const iterator end() const;
private:
    size_t capacity;
    int* data;
};
```

The error I'm getting on begin and end is the following: `Error: Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone.`

I know you're not allowed to have the same function name and same parameters with different return types, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? Am I making the iterator right? Would a template help fix this? I need `begin()` and `end()` to return both an `int*` and an `iterator` so I can pass both test cases. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Get rid of the pointer returns and only return iterators?

Comment: And fix the testcases, what they're asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need `begin()` and `end()` to return both an `int*` and an `iterator` so I can pass both test cases.

No, you don't. The test case expecting a pointer is wrong. Containers give you back iterators. In your case, your iterator could *be* a pointer, but that's an implementation detail. You definitely just want:

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const; // NB: const_iterator, not const iterator
```

And then fix your unit test to expect `RandomArray::iterator` instead of `int*`. Or, even better, `auto`.

---

Note: Your `operator++()` does postfix increment instead of prefix increment. Also `const reference` is the wrong type, that woudl be `int& const`, and references are inherently `const`. You want to change your typedef for `reference` to itself be `int const&`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the test case with `int *b = r.begin();` (though if this is a new class, why not?) then you need to either make your iterator type *be* the pointer type, or be *convertible to* the pointer type.

In the first case, get rid of the `iterator` classes and write `using iterator = int*;` `using const_iterator = int const*;`.

In the second case, add conversion functions `operator pointer() const { return ptr; }`.

The second case is better, as this allows you to deprecate the conversion function in future. However it would be even better to fix the test case to use the iterator type.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. All I had to do was declare a typedef iterator as an int*.

Updated Code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int* begin();

    const int* begin() const;

    int* end();

    const int* end() const;

    //HERE
    typedef int* iterator;
    typedef const int* const_iterator;
private:
    size_t capacity;
    int* data;
};
```

Then, in the function body I changed it to this:

```
int* MyClass::begin()
{
    return iterator(&data[0]);
}

const int* MyClass::begin() const
{
    return const_iterator(&data[0]);
}

int* MyClass::end()
{
    return iterator(&data[capacity]);
}

const int* MyClass::end() const
{
    return const_iterator(&data[capacity]);
}
```

Comment: `iterator(&data[0])`  is the same thing as `iterator(data)` is the same thing as `data`. No need for all the extra stuff.